# ColorSplash effect tutorial for java or android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a colorsplash effect in android. A grayscale image that can be colored with a brush and also paint it again to a grayscale with other brush.

I managed to paint the colors using setXfermode on the canvas but I'm not able to paint the grayscale again.

I'm looking for a tutorial or a simple example of it. I found lots of android apps that can do it but nothing related on how they did it.

```
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (isBlackAndWhite) {
        //draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);


        //copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole in it
        //c2.drawBitmap(overlayDefault, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
        if (isErase) {
            c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, mPaintTransparent);
        } else {
            c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, mPaintNormal);
        }

        //draw the overlay over the background
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

So my background is the colored image and the overlay is the grayscale filtered image
mPainttransparent is as Paint object with

setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR))

My problem now is that I can't paint it back to normal

Comment: Please show the code you're using

Comment: I never heard of this. can you store first state(pixels) in some variable or array or something then when you want them back read them from that variable?

Comment: I edited my post to add the code